# Downloading product adds “attachment” word to file name in chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, chrome-browser

Hi i have downloadable products in my store. When customer download products except from chrome it's work fine.
but when customer downloads products from chrome then it adds "attachment" word like (abc.mp3, attachment). I userd default
function of magento for download

```
$sampleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sample_id', 0);
    $sample = Mage::getModel('downloadable/sample')->load($sampleId);
    if ($sample->getId()) {
        $resource = '';
        $resourceType = '';
        if ($sample->getSampleType() == Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::LINK_TYPE_URL) {
            $resource = $sample->getSampleUrl();
            $resourceType = Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::LINK_TYPE_URL;
        } elseif ($sample->getSampleType() == Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::LINK_TYPE_FILE) {
            $resource = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->getFilePath(
                Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sample::getBasePath(), $sample->getSampleFile()
            );
            $resourceType = Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::LINK_TYPE_FILE;
        }
        try {
            parent::_processDownload($resource, $resourceType);
            exit(0);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Sorry, there was an error getting requested content. Please contact the store owner.'));
        }
    }
    return $this->_redirectReferer();
```

Comment: I think this is just the way the browser displays the download.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot where the "attachment" text is added?